# Выравнивание ребенка с нечетной величиной ширины в нутри родителя с четной величиной ширины

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

В родительском блоке с четной величиной ширины блока -
существует ли возможность с позиционировать(или выровнять) по середине
  этого родителя - ребенка с нечетной величиной ширины?
Для примера можно взять родителя с шириной 10 пикселей и ребенка с шириной 1 пиксель.
Возможно ли ребенка спозиционировать по середине такого родителя?

Comment: может зависеть от конкретного браузера

Comment: Пока что у меня ни в каком браузере не удалось получить выравнивание - и даже не могу представить как это можно сделать хоть в каком то - какие есть варианты?

Comment: `width:10px; display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1px 1fr;` развлекайтесь =) p.s. в браузерах и в прошлом веке было масштабирование на сколько помню, а благодаря зоопарку актуальных разрешений и DPI(у свежей мобилы 7" разрешение легко может быть выше чем у не сильно старого 30" монитора) оно перешло в разряд must have, из-за чего px указываемый в css с реальными габаритами пикселя иметь что то общее не обязан совсем. в инспекторе пощупайте указанный мной выше пример, там наверняка боковые столбцы будут иметь ширину около 8.33...3px. ну как px, виртуальных px...

Comment: http://joxi.ru/MAjdQLoHde8O5m
Так. Этот способ не помог к сожалению. )

Comment: У родителя там ширина 100% которая дает на выходе от 9.71667px до 9.73334px - в зависимости от сгенерированного елемента.